# Is it possible to make a restriction on a nested complex type

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, restriction, complextype

Here is my naive example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:complexType name="dog">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:choice>
                        <xs:element name="known" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="unknown"/>
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="bigDog">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="dog">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice>
                                <xs:element name="known" type="xs:string"/>
                                <xs:element name="unknown"/>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string" fixed="grand danois"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Oxygen gives me: Error for type 'bigDog'. The particle oftype is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what it does that. Maybe an error of XSD 1.0 ? But this is valid

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

     <xs:complexType name="dogNameType">
         <xs:choice>
             <xs:element name="known" type="xs:string"/>
             <xs:element name="unknown"/>
         </xs:choice>
     </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="dog">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="dogNameType"/>
            <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="bigDog">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:restriction base="dog">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="dogNameType"/>
                    <xs:element name="breed" type="xs:string" fixed="grand danois"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```